# Looping through columns using number in column name

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I have the following columns in my pandas dataframe - client_1_name, client_2_name, clinet_3_name... all the way to client_10_name.

I want to loop through the columns names using the number in the column name to identify whether the specific column contains a substring - "Nike".

How I would ideally approach the problem:

```
for i in range(1,10):
 df['Nike'] = df['Client_'+i+'_name'].str.contains('Nike', regex = True)
```

but I got the following error

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-85-28926af604a8> in <module>()
          2 
          3 for i in range(1,10):
    ----> 4     df_nike['Nike'] = df_nike['client_'+i+'_name'].str.contains('Nike', regex = True)

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the integer to a string before concatentating

```
for i in range(1,10):
# added `str()` around the `i`
    df['Nike'] = df['Client_'+str(i)+'_name'].str.contains('Nike', regex = True)
```

If you are using Python 3.6+ you can use f strings

```
for i in range(1,10):
# added `f` at the beginning of the string and {} around `i`
    df['Nike'] = df[f'Client_{i}_name'].str.contains('Nike', regex = True)
```

As @Wen-Ben mentioned in the second part of his answer, looping through the columns will result in the overwriting of your new "Nike" column. If you truly want to check all of the columns without overwriting "Nike", you should add `i` to the column name like so

```
for i in range(1,10):
# added `f` at the beginning of the string and {} around `i`
    df[f'Nike{i}'] = df[f'Client_{i}_name'].str.contains('Nike', regex = True)
```

Comment: beautiful, it worked very well. Can you point me to some documentation on this f'? How does it work?

Comment: Sure. Looks like it's written in PEP 498 --> https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Comment: I think I have a problem, if the Client_1_name contains 'Nike', bu Client_10_name doesn't, df['Nike'] is going to return 0, instead of 1, right? how can i specify "any of these columns"?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you need to do , but simple fix your code add `str`

```
for i in range(1,10):
   df['Nike'] = df['Client_'+str(i)+'_name'].str.contains('Nike', regex = True) # notice here you assign the value to one columns 10 times
```

---

You may want to

```
for i in range(1,10):
   df['Nike'+str(i)] = df['Client_'+str(i)+'_name'].str.contains('Nike', regex = True)
```

Comment: I think I have a problem, if the Client_1_name contains 'Nike', bu Client_10_name doesn't, df['Nike'] is going to return 0, instead of 1, right? how can i specify "any of these columns"?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this Dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.choice(list('ABCDEFGH')+['Nike'], 100).reshape(10,10), columns = ['Client_'+str(i)+'_name' for i in range(1,11)])
```

You can check if the column contains Nike using

```
df.eq('Nike').any()

Client_1_name      True
Client_2_name     False
Client_3_name     False
Client_4_name      True
Client_5_name     False
Client_6_name      True
Client_7_name      True
Client_8_name      True
Client_9_name      True
Client_10_name     True
```

If you want to extract the column names, try

```
s = df.eq('Nike').any()
s[s].index

Index(['Client_1_name', 'Client_4_name', 'Client_6_name', 'Client_7_name',
   'Client_8_name', 'Client_9_name', 'Client_10_name'],
  dtype='object')
```

If you want to extract only the number, try

```
s[s].index.str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int).values.ravel().tolist()

[1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```